# From jFreeChart Millisecond to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, jfreechart, milliseconds

Regarding jFreeChart's [Millisecond](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Millisecond.html),

How can I get a [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object from a `Millisecond` instance?

From the docs, it only seems possible to subtract the milliseconds within `Millisecond`.

Since a `Millisecond` object is constructed like so:

```
  Millisecond ms = new Millisecond(
           millisec, 
           second,
           minute,
           hour,
           day,
           month,
           year);
```

I should be able to extract a valid `Date` object as well.

### Edit

I need a `Date` object that gives back the **exact** time up to the millisecond accurate.

Does `.getStart()` provide this?

**[ANSWER]**: YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Millisecond is like any other RegularTimePeriod in JFreeChart, so you can just

```
    Date d = ms.getStart();
```

or

```
    Date d = ms.getEnd();
```

depending on whether you want a date referring to the beginning or the end of your millisecond (same value either way).

See [The JFreeChart API](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Millisecond.html) for more info.

EDIT: Adding code here since comments kill formatting:

```
    Millisecond ms = new Millisecond();
    System.out.println(ms.getStart().getTime());
    System.out.println(ms.getEnd().getTime());
```

will print the same millisecond twice.

Comment: so `.getStart()` will give me the exact date up to the millisecond I put in? (I'm working with millisecond data so this is crucial to know for me). And `.getEnd()` will give me the **next** millisecond?

Comment: No, it's still the same millisecond, since it only has millisecond precision.  I added a snippet to my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the `Millisecond` Class represents the time period of a millisecond and I'd assume the the `getStart` and `getEnd` Methods inherited from `RegularTimePeriod` return (nearly) the same `Date` of which one is one you're looking for.

Comment: I need the **exact** `Date` unfortunately (I am working with millisecond data)

Comment: As I said: millisecond represents the period of one millisecond in time. So you meed to decide if you want the start or the end - which probably will two consecutive milliseconds.

Comment: Actually they are the same (see answer above)

Comment: Ahh... Thank's. Seems strange to me anyway, because I'd say the end of this millisecond is the start of the very next one.

Answer (score 0):

(my answer was late) Perhaps you could use this code:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(freeMillis.getMillisecond());
```

edit: scrap that, freeMillis.getMillisecond() returns just a millisecond part.

Comment: Doesn't `.getMillisecond()` give back the millisecond only?

Comment: System.out.println(new Date(ms.getMillisecond())); doesn't work. It returns `Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970`